# Is it possible to write a python script just to create a new spyder console?

Tags: python, console, spyder

Is it possible to write a python script just to create a new spyder console? As I try to execute another file after executing the main file and hoping to display all the results in the new console. Thank you.

Comment: What is a spyder console?

Comment: It's actually just the console in Spyder.

Comment: Can you explain how exactly you plan for it to work. The console in Spyder is just Ipython so there are two relatively simple options - you can either call `ipython` through subprocess or you could simulate a `Ctrl+T` key combination which creates another tab in Ipython within Spyder.

Comment: I just don't fully understand what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Actually, for manual input, the "Ctrl + T" can fulfill my requirement. But as I would like to write some codes in the first file, and after executing this file, a new console will be created so that my second file could be executed and display its results onto the new console.

Comment: So do you want to execute both scripts in parallel? You should look into using `threading` or `multiprocessing` to do this properly.